Throughput Rate in Fixed Intervals and Plotting
I am struggling to make a time plot (line chart) which shows the passengers processed (throughput) in 15-minutes for the eGates.

Am I on the right path thinking I need to a variable which counts ped_eGates on enter and then get sent to the dataset every 15-minute by an event, then the dataset is used in the time plot, then reset back to 0?
Also, bonus points if somebody can get the time plot to have the actually timestamp on the x-axis: As close to this line chart which we use to get data from the real world process:

Thanks!


Am I on the right path thinking I need to a variable which counts ped_eGates on enter and then get sent to the dataset every 15-minute by an event, then the dataset is used in the time plot, then reset back to 0?

yes

Also, bonus points if somebody can get the time plot to have the actually timestamp on the x-axis: As close to this line chart which we use to get data from the real world process:

Check the properties of the time chart: you can define the x-axis labels (default is "model time units", change that to HH:mm)
